# How to get element 's css position in d3 or native javascript API

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I have a HTML5 list

when I click each

, I want to get the absolute position / relative position of

element. since I am using the d3.js and angular.js

I have tried native javascript API and d3.js

```
 var d = document.querySelectorAll('#a1');          

 console.log('select index  ', d3.selectAll( '#a1' ).attr('x'), d.offsetLeft, d.offsetTop);
```

but the code doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Without a framework, determining the position of a DOM element can be tricky, as this element can be absolutely positioned, or embedded in another element with its own offset.

Write a function to traverse the element's parents all the way to the document root, and add up the top and left offset values, as a very basic implementation.

```
function MyPosX(node,x){
  if (node.parentNode==document.body) return node.offsetLeft;
  return x+MyPosX(node.parentNode.offsetLeft,x);
}

alert(MyPosX(document.getElementById('test'),0));
```

Please double check the parent pointers and boundary conditions. The above code is for illustration only.

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll` returns a non-live NodeList, therefore, to really select the element that you need, you must include an index like so:

```
var d = document.querySelectorAll('#a1')[0]; //assuming that there is an element with this ID
```

It would be much easier to just use `document.getElementById("a1")` in this case though.

```
var d = document.getElementById("a1");
```

*[More info on getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)*

*[Potential duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element)*